# Bringing classes together in a cohesive way

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, simulator, composition

I've been working on a making a simulation of the Game of War card game in order to gather statistics on how many turns it takes to complete.

I've created a Player class and a Deck class to hand their respective roles but I'm stumped as for how to bring them together in a cohesive way. I need an environment where the hands of the game can play out. I thought of just handling this all in the main but it seems like that would be a mess.

I've also thought of making another class comprised of the Player and Deck objects. i just dont know what the best way to bring these classes together is.

PLAYER:

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    void placeCardInHand(int); //cards placed in hand will be placed pushed to the front
    int getCardFromHand();  // cards leaving the hand will be popped from the front
    bool handIsEmpty(); //if the players hand is empty return true
private:
    deque<int> hand; // the players hand can hold an entire deck of cards.

};



 void Player::placeCardInHand(int aCard)
{
    hand.push_front(aCard); //card is pushed to the front of the hand
}

int Player::getCardFromHand()
{
    int temp = hand.front(); //get the first item in the hand
    hand.pop_front();   // remove the first item from the hand

    return temp;    //return that item
}

bool Player::handIsEmpty()
{
    return this->hand.empty(); 
}
```

DECK:

```
class Deck
{
public:
    Deck(); //deck starts with 52 cards in order 0 - 51

    void shuffleTheDeck();  //one call to this completely shuffles the deck
    int drawCard(); //gives the card on top then pops from the deck

    void showDeck();        //nessesary for testing

private:
    deque<int> theDeck;
};

Deck::Deck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        this->theDeck.push_front(i); //fill the deck with 52 cards 0 - 51
    }
}

void Deck::shuffleTheDeck() //pick two random positions and swap the cards
{
    int temp;
    int position1;
    int position2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {

        position1 = rand() % 52;    //there is only 52 positions in the deck this prevents going out of bounds
        position2 = rand() % 52;

        temp = this->theDeck[position1];
        this->theDeck[position1] = this->theDeck[position2];
        this->theDeck[position2] = temp;
    }

}

int Deck::drawCard()
{
    int temp = theDeck.front(); //gets the top card
    theDeck.pop_front();    //pops top card

    return temp;    //returns top card
}

void Deck::showDeck()
{
    deque<int> temporaryDeck = this->theDeck;
    while (temporaryDeck.empty() != true)
    {
        cout << temporaryDeck.front() << " ";
        temporaryDeck.pop_front();
    }
    cout << endl;
}

    Deck::Deck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        this->theDeck.push_front(i); //fill the deck with 52 cards 0 - 51
    }
}

void Deck::shuffleTheDeck() //pick two random positions and swap the cards
{
    int temp;
    int position1;
    int position2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {

        position1 = rand() % 52;    //there is only 52 positions in the deck this prevents going out of bounds
        position2 = rand() % 52;

        temp = this->theDeck[position1];
        this->theDeck[position1] = this->theDeck[position2];
        this->theDeck[position2] = temp;
    }

}

int Deck::drawCard()
{
    int temp = theDeck.front(); //gets the top card
    theDeck.pop_front();    //pops top card

    return temp;    //returns top card
}

void Deck::showDeck()
{
    deque<int> temporaryDeck = this->theDeck;
    while (temporaryDeck.empty() != true)
    {
        cout << temporaryDeck.front() << " ";
        temporaryDeck.pop_front();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Currently the main is where I am working on all the actions of the game. As an example, I have implemented the way dealing would work. but is there a better way so that i could reuse the code?

```
int main() {
Deck cards;
Player player1, player2;
deque<int> field;

cards.shuffleTheDeck(); //shuffle the deck
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)    //deal the cards
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        player1.placeCardInHand(cards.drawCard());
    }
    else
    {
        player2.placeCardInHand(cards.drawCard());
    }
}

while (!player1.handIsEmpty() && !player2.handIsEmpty()) //turns start
{




} //game over


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make a `Game` object.  It holds the players and the deck and then you can use member functions to control what step to do.

Comment: If you're asking for advice about improvement and refactoring already working code, your question will be welcome at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).